# webpacker - how to identify dependencies and eventually apply an update

Tags: ruby-on-rails, webpacker

An application is not deployable because of node-gyp 3.8.0 which is nto compatible with `Python 3.8.10 (default, Mar 13 2023, 10:26:41)` installed on the machine.  This issue emerged all of a sudden without any modifications to the application's `package.json` file.

The dependency is generated by `node-sass` - but what if one does not use sass?  Yet webpacker goes ahead and installs it.  `node-modules/node-sass/package.json` gives

```
{
  "name": "node-sass",
  "version": "4.14.1",
```

`node-modules/.yarn-integrity` instead refers to
`"node-sass@^4.13.0": "https://registry.yarnpkg.com/node-sass/-/node-sass-4.14.1.tgz#99c87ec2efb7047ed638fb4c9db7f3a42e2217b5",`  possibly because  `node_modules/@rails/webpacker/package.json` has

```
{
  "name": "@rails/webpacker",
  "version": "4.3.0",
   [...] },
  "dependencies": {
[...]
    "node-sass": "^4.13.0",
```

While the [repository for node-gyp](https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp)  states

```
Multiple target versions of Node.js are supported (i.e. 0.8, ..., 4, 5, 6, etc.),  
regardless of what version of Node.js is actually installed on your system  
(node-gyp downloads the necessary development files or headers for the target version).
```

This is not of much use given webpacker in the middle (I believe).

a) how can one determine what or which dependency invokes node-sass (and thus determine whether the upstream package needs updating) ?
b) where can I find relative info on the version to install for the version of python ?
c) how should the package.json file be modified?
d) better yet, if sass is not the be used, how can webpacker ignore it?

Comment: Try [`yarn why node-sass`](https://yarnpkg.com/cli/why). Also even if you are using SASS node-sass has been deprechiated. https://sass-lang.com/blog/libsass-is-deprecated

Comment: that was useful. To whom it may concern... `"@rails#webpacker" depends on it`  and the config/package.json defines `"@rails/webpacker": "4.3.0",` which in turn is set by the gem definition which was set yonks ago `gem 'webpacker', '~> 4.0'` while the package.json file was invoking version 4.3.0.  None of these **actually** changed without calling `yarn install` on the local development version before updating the main repository.

Comment: The latest verison of webpacker is 5.4.4 and which should be compatible with Rails 5.2+ (based on the gemspec).

Comment: Yes, that was the route chosen and it runs as expected (it is also the end-of-the-line version for webpacker): however the above elements noted may be of use to others, as the steps are not explicitely indicated.